# unordered list in contentful-rich-text rendering as P tags

Tags: reactjs, graphql, contentful

Iv'e got a list of bullet points in my contentful space, but It shows up as P tags for some reason. I've tried using LIST_ITEM but, still same result. I just need the bullet points to show up. I think I'm missing a rich-text type but I'm not sure which one?

```
const options = {
    renderMark: {
        [BLOCKS.LIST_ITEM]: (children) => 
            <li style={{ fontSize: '60px', fontFamily: 'Montserrat' }}>{children}</li>,
    },
};

<ul className="leading-8">
    <li>{renderRichText(data.contentfulReports.fullDescription, options)}</li>
</ul>
```

here is my query

```
query MyBlogs($slug: String) {
    contentfulReports(slug: { eq: $slug }) {
        title
        slug
        summary {
            summary
        }
        table {
            tableData
        }
        fullDescription {
            raw
        }
        bannerImage {
            fluid {
              src
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of renderMark try to use renderNode:

```
renderNode: {
      [BLOCKS.PARAGRAPH]: (node, children) => <p>{children}</p>,
      [BLOCKS.UL_LIST]: (node, children) => (
        <ul>{children}</ul>
      ),
      [BLOCKS.OL_LIST]: (node, children) => (
        <ol>{children}</ol>
      ),
      [BLOCKS.LIST_ITEM]: (node, children) => <li>{children}</li>,
}
```

In our case we are querying json instead of raw:

```
fullDescription {
      json
}
```

And use the documentToReactComponents function:

```
import { documentToReactComponents } from "@contentful/rich-text-react-renderer";
…
documentToReactComponents(fulldescription.json, options)
```

Comment: how would it work with raw though? would the solution still work?

Comment: It would work the same, the main takeaway here is that renderNode uses BLOCKS and renderMark for MARKS (only BOLD, CODE, ITALIC, UNDERLINE) which is better explained on https://github.com/contentful/rich-text/tree/master/packages/rich-text-react-renderer